# Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 analytics-event listeners added

Tags: javascript, dom, memory-leaks, dom-events, eventemitter

I have a set of hyperlinks in my chatbot with class name of "q_link". I added a click event to the document to recognize wehenver the target is the link.

```
    document.addEventListener("click" ,(event) => {
    if(event.target.className === "q_link")
    {   
        webchat.sendMessage(event.target.innerText);
        event.target.setAttribute('disabled', '');
    }
    })
```

What happens is when the flow starts and I click on the hyperlink then the required message gets displayed once but when the flow ends and the flow goes back to start and then if I click on the hyperlink then the required message is displayed twice and the number of messages sent increases each time the flow ends and goes to the start of the flow until I get the above error.

How to fix this?

Comment: Where exactly in your code does the above code exist? Can you post the context around that event handler assignment?

Comment: @Pointy I have added the code at the start of the js file which is added at the start of the flow of the bot. In relation to the event handler, I have a set of hyperlinks in my bot and I used above code to recognigze whenvever the link is clicked in the document.

Comment: Well what you described sounds like what would happen if you added that "click" event handler over and over again somehow. Often that's caused by code that adds a handler like that from *inside* another event handler.